# Is it possible to place a label midway of an edge in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz

Is is possible to make a graph like this:

[image: Graph]

Where the label is in the path of an edge between two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you get, as far as I know, is rather than trying to fiddle around with edge lables, using text only nodes:

```
digraph so 
{
    // standard nodes
    node[ shape = box ];
    A[ label = "Animal" ];
    B[ label = "Elephant" ];

    // fake label nodes
    node[ shape = none ];
    a[ label = " large" ];

    // get them connected
    edge[ arrowhead = none ];
    A -> a -> B;
}
```

This gives you

[image]

This is not optimal as it gives you layout problems - the distance between your "real" nodes is probably larger than you want, and you would have to introduce empty nodes for edges without labels. But at least it comes close to the picture you have posted.